# RightToLeft on inputBox - VB

Tags: vb.net, right-to-left, inputbox

How to create an inputBox that it will be in 'RightToLeft', that all text and buttons in the InputBox Will be from Right to Left in VB?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, just make a form that looks like a `InputBox` and and set it up as you want (RightToLeft) and set it to be shown in the center of the screen and set the `Enable` property for your main form to false when showing the `InputBox` so the user will not be able to use the main form unless he closes the "fake" `InputBox`, just like the real one, i think this is the only way.

Comment: I would suggest that noone should ever use `InputBox` in a real application anyway. It is dodgy for numerous reasons. Always create your own dialogues and then display them by calling `ShowDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Most individual Windows Forms controls have a Right-To-Left property. I suggest that instead of creating an InputBox, you create a form using TextBox and Button controls with Right-to-Left turned on.

There is pretty decent (if slightly dated) information on globalizing Windows forms here: [Microsoft Develop Network: Globalizing Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xdxwwkc(v=vs.100).aspx)